# Evaluating an integral with a complex constant

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

> $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(-s + ai)t} dt$$

$s > 0, a$ both real.

I got that

$$\int e^{(-s + ai)t} dt = \frac{e^{(-s + ai)t}}{ai - s} + C$$

But the confusion is with the definite $[0, \infty)$, how does one evaluate that?

Comment: Is $i$ the imaginary number? How have you defined complex integration? What you have is basically a path integral in the complex plane where we simply choose the non-negative real line as our path, but there are some technical nuances with this you might want to be careful with

Comment: Are $a$ and $s$ real and is $s > 0$?

Comment: As shown by [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+infinity+of+e%5E((a*i-s)x)+dx), your integral converges for $\Im(a) + \Re(s)>0$ (which is the meaning behind Tilper's comment above). As long as you keep this in mind, you can calculate the integral using the antiderivative easily - just factor out the $\frac{1}{ai-s}$ from the antiderivative and note that your exponential goes to $0$ at infinity and goes to $1$ at zero. Conclude.

Comment: @tilper, yes, they are

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, I've edited. $s > 0,$ and $a$ is real

Comment: Just use the classic $\sigma \delta$ approach.